# Identifying parts of speech for individual words (not texts)

Tags: nlp

Please forgive the potential ignorance of this question. I am not a complete virgin regarding NLP:

I am trying to assign parts of speech to individual words. I realize that many words can serve as multiple parts of speech, but I am looking for the POS that a human would be most likely to interpret the word as, seeing it out of context.

Is there any database that has this info in it for a reasonably large set of words? Or, is there any large corpus with POS tags where I could feed it  words, and get frequency distributions of the POS that each word is playing in the corpus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry about single words. State-of-the-art PoST models are typically based on Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs). They take sequences of words as inputs, and classify them based on their context words. If your model is good, a single word that is part of a broader expression should be classifier correctly.

The main dataset that I reccomend is the free part of the Penn Treebank dataset, available from python library **nltk**. From the same module you can also download the Brown corpus. there are compatibility problems between the two (the PoS tags are different), however you could assemble them together using universal tagset (less precise, but applicable to both).

Additionally, check this [great Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/abhinavwalia95/entity-annotated-corpus/version/4). It's a dataset for both PoST and NER tasks, and you can use it to train your classifier. (It seems the tagset is the same of Penn Treebank, which means you might assemble the two datasets into an even bigger one.)

Answer (score 0):

A POS tagged dataset that might help: [link](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/conll2000/chunking/)

Comment: Please elaborate an answer. Single link posts are discouraged on StackExchange.